# When taking damage to an outfit, does damaging an arming space also apply a -1 to the outfit's die?

Tags: xia

The Xia rules are just slightly vague about damage to outfits. It has two separate sections for "putting damage on an outfit" and "putting damage on a use space":

> **Use Space:** If the (damage marker) is placed on a Use Space of an Outfit, any Markers are immediately moved to a Disarmed Space, and the Use Space is no longer usable until repaired.
>
> **Outfits:** Damage Markers can be placed on any Section of an Outfit. Each
> Section of the Outfit can hold one (damage marker). Damage Markers on an Outfit cause that
> Outfit to become less effective. Each (damage marker) placed on an Outfit reduces rolls by 1.

Do these two descriptions stack, so that putting a damage marker on a use space of an outfit causes *both* -1 to rolls with that outfit *and* the arming spot cannot be used? Or are they separate, so that if you decide to damage an outfit, you have to choose between losing a use space *or* having the outfit be less effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They stack.

`Damage Markers can be placed on any Section of an Outfit`

An outfit is made up of sections of two types; use spaces and empty spaces for storing cargo i.e. A use space is considered to be a section of an outfit. Therefore this rule

`Damage Markers on an Outfit cause that Outfit to become less effective. Each (damage  marker) placed on an Outfit reduces rolls by 1`

means that damage anywhere on an outfit will cause it to be less effective.